# rvest & parsing HTML: find a list of items, and extract specific information from each item

Tags: html, r, dplyr, rvest

I'm struggling to find neat code to do the following:

- Find a list of five items
- Iterate over all five items
- Extract 4 columns from each item
- return a dataframe with five rows, one for each item.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="i-am-a-list">
    <div class="item item-one"><a href=""></a><a class="title"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
    <div class="item item-two"><a href=""></a><a class="title-two"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
    <div class="item item-three"><a href=""></a><a class="title-three"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
    <div class="item item-four"><a href=""></a><a class="title-for"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
    <div class="item item-five"><a href=""></a><a class="title-five"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>

</div>
```

Code thus far:

```
# find the upper list   
coll <- read_html(doc.html) %>%
  html_node('.i-am-a-list') %>%
  html_nodes(".item")

# problems here, how do I iterate over the returned divs 
# I was expecting something like
results <- coll %>% 
    do(parse_a_single_item) %>%
    rbind_all()
```

Would it be possible to write such pretty code to do such a common task? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really pretty and I feel like I'm missing some obvious method, but you can do:

```
library(rvest)
library(purrr)

read_html(x) %>%
  html_node('.i-am-a-list') %>%
  html_nodes(".item") %>% 
  map_df(~{
    class = html_attr(.x, 'class')
    a1 = html_nodes(.x, 'a') %>% '['(1) %>% html_attr('href')
    a2 = html_nodes(.x, 'a') %>% '['(2) %>% html_attr('class')
    # or with CSS selector
    # a1 = html_nodes(.x, 'a:first-child') %>% html_attr('href')
    # a2 = html_nodes(.x, 'a:nth-child(2)') %>% html_attr('class')
    p = html_nodes(.x, 'p') %>% html_text()
    data.frame(class, a1, a2, p)
    })

#             class a1          a2         p
# 1   item item-one          title sub-title
# 2   item item-two      title-two sub-title
# 3 item item-three    title-three sub-title
# 4  item item-four      title-for sub-title
# 5  item item-five     title-five sub-title
```

data:

```
x <- '<div class="i-am-a-list">
  <div class="item item-one"><a href=""></a><a class="title"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
  <div class="item item-two"><a href=""></a><a class="title-two"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
  <div class="item item-three"><a href=""></a><a class="title-three"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
  <div class="item item-four"><a href=""></a><a class="title-for"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
  <div class="item item-five"><a href=""></a><a class="title-five"></a><p>sub-title</p></div>
</div>'
```

Comment: that's def a great way to do it. cld target each anchor tag with CSS vs `[` but apart from that it's a ++gd solution

Comment: This, sir, is pretty awesome already. Even before I finished my much, much, less pretty code. Appreciate it!